# Add element to an array and remove the element from front, one at a time, every 2 seconds until the array is empty?

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, react-native

So, I'm using react and have a button which adds an element to an array using useState when I press the button. Now, once I've added the 1st element, I want to remove the first element after every 1 second until the array is empty and I'm not pressing the button anymore.

I could keep pressing and add items but after 2 seconds has passed, maybe using a timer, it should also keep removing from the front of the array.

```
const [id, addId] = useState([])

<button onClick={()=> addId([...id,newId])> Add Id </button>
```

So, I have got a view that loops through the IDs and paints them on the screen. Now, as it gets painted, it should fade away and also get removed from the array after I first press the button and remove them every 2 seconds.

I'm not able to use setInterval, setTimeout and useEffect properly. It ends up in an infinite loop...

Let's say, I press 3 times, the array would be [1,2,3] and after 1 second, it should be [2,3] then after 1 second, it should be [3] and finally stop with an empty array []. Once I press the button the removing process should not stop until the array is empty even when I stop pressing the button.

Hope it's clear now to what I want

Comment: what does not work?

Comment: I have updated the issue @NinaScholz

Answer (score 1):

This is my stab at it, though it's perhaps a bit messier than I'd like:

(Edit: this is based on the codesandbox link BTW.)

```
import React from "react";
import "./styles.css";

export default function App() {
  const delay = 2000;
  const [ids, setIds] = React.useState([]);

  const timeout = React.useRef(null);
  const ids_length = React.useRef(null);

  function set_remove_ids_timeout() {
    if(timeout.current)
      clearTimeout(timeout.current);
    
    timeout.current = setTimeout(() => {
      if (ids_length.current === 0) return;
      ids_length.current = ids_length.current - 1;
      setIds(([first, ...others]) => [...others]);
      set_remove_ids_timeout();
    }, delay);
  }

  function add() {
    ids_length.current = ids.length + 1;
    setIds([...ids, (ids[ids.length - 1] || 0) + 1]);
    set_remove_ids_timeout();
  }

  React.useEffect(() => {
    return () => { if(timeout.current) clearTimeout(timeout.current); };
  }, []);

  console.log("ids adding", ids);
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <button onClick={add}> Add Id </button>
      {ids.map((i) => (
        <p key={i}>{i}</p>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
}
```

Edit ... so it's possible that I didn't / don't understand exactly when removal resumes after button click ... so if button click is not supposed to affect the delay for removal maybe something like this would work:

```
import React from "react";
import "./styles.css";

export default function App() {
  const delay = 2000;
  const [ids, setIds] = React.useState([]);

  const interval = React.useRef(null);
  const ids_length = React.useRef(null);

  function set_remove_ids_interval() {
    if (!interval.current) {
      interval.current = setInterval(() => {
        console.log("ids_length.current", ids_length.current);
        if (ids_length.current === 0) {
          clearInterval(interval.current);
          interval.current = null;
          return;
        }
        ids_length.current = ids_length.current - 1;
        setIds(([first, ...others]) => [...others]);
        set_remove_ids_interval();
      }, delay);
    }
  }

  function add() {
    ids_length.current = ids.length + 1;
    setIds([...ids, (ids[ids.length - 1] || 0) + 1]);
    set_remove_ids_interval();
  }

  React.useEffect(() => {
    return () => {
      if (interval.current) clearInterval(interval.current);
    };
  }, []);

  console.log("ids adding", ids);
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <button onClick={add}> Add Id </button>
      {ids.map((i) => (
        <p key={i}>{i}</p>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: Hey Ben Stephen, this works for what I needed, thank, but, could it be done without the use of ref?

Comment: @Rishav I think you could try declaring `let interval` and `let ids_length` outside of the component scope (like in stellyrepsolka's answer but (I think) let instead of const) but (as per Emile Bergeron's comment) that limits you to using one instance of the component. You might be able to use state for interval_id but I'd wonder if by the time the function passed to setInterval is run the interval_id inside that function would be stale so then clearInterval(interval_id) wouldn't work. I think using state for ids_length would not work as in the interval function it is likely to be stale.

Comment: @Rishav why might you not want to use a ref?

Comment: This works but, I heard that using ref is not the best way and we should avoid using it as much as possible. So wanted to know, but thanks a lot, it works!

Answer (score 0):

You could take `setInterval` and check if the array has values.

```js
function add() {
    array.push(Math.floor(Math.random() * 10));
    document.getElementById('values').innerHTML = array.join(' ');
}

const array = [];

setInterval(() => {
    if (!array.length) return;
    array.shift();
    document.getElementById('values').innerHTML = array.join(' ');
}, 1000);
```

```html
<button onclick="add()">click</button><br>
<div id="values"></div>
```

A slightly better approach where the interval loops only if at least a value is in the array.

```js
function showValues() {
    document.getElementById('values').innerHTML = array.join(' ');
}

function add() {
    array.push(Math.floor(Math.random() * 10));
    showValues();
    if (interval === undefined) interval = setInterval(intervalFn, 1000);
}

function intervalFn() {
    array.shift();
    showValues();
    if (!array.length) {
        clearInterval(interval);
        interval = undefined;
    }
}

let array = [],
    interval;
```

```html
<button onclick="add()">click</button><br>
<div id="values"></div>
```

Comment: This works but, my component is not re-rendering so I'm not able to see the elements go away. I need this to work on React. https://codesandbox.io/s/busy-fermat-3nrrt?file=/src/App.js. The effect should be similar to the numbers I'm displaying inside a <p> tag.

Comment: sorry i have no idea of *react*.

Comment: Thanks for this, really appreciate it! It's a start. @Nina Scholz

Answer (score 0):

```
const interval = null;

const Component = () => {

    const [array, setArray] = useState([]);

    useEffect(() =>  

         if (interval === null) {
              interval = setInterval(() => {
                   if (array.length > 0) {
                     const [first, ...newArray] = array;
                     setArray(newArray);
                   }

              }, 1000);
         }

        () => clearInterval(interval)
     ), []);

   return ( put code that you want to render );
}
```

Initialize interval variable outside a component so it will not change if any re-renders happen in component. In component did mount (use effect) set interv that will trigger every second and remove element from array (shift or pop) and update a state. And on unmounting clear the interval.

Comment: `.shift` mutates the array in place.

Comment: yeah, I made a mistake. I fixed it.

Comment: Also, just noticed that `interval` is defined outside of the `useEffect`, which means that if another instance of the component ever gets created, it'll break.

Comment: Just realized that you're using `array`, which gets captured on component's mount and it never gets new values, so this won't work either. You'd need to use the updater callback parameter: `setArray(([first, ...newArray]) => newArray)`